# How can i remove all the numbers from a string in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I need to remove all the numbers from a string, but the code that I have is in swift 2.3

```
let string = (string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")
```

How can I do the same in swift 3? thanks!

Comment: Google: https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=remove+numbers+from+string+swift&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=FVRqWb_-OaPH8AfGpbOgAw#q=remove+numbers+from+string+swift+3 all answers are there

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Xcode compiler will help you with this, if not it's a _very_ simple change with which Google will definitely be you friend!

Comment: I try to search on Google, I come down empty.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this code

```
let string = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits).joined()
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's working